# Using Office.js with Word 2010

Tags: javascript, xml, ms-word, ms-office

I've been looking for some help online for implementing Office.js with Word 2010.  I know I've seen implementation of OOXML with Word 2010, but I haven't seen much about the use of Office.js with Word 2010.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office.js defines the API for the new JavaScript-based so-called *Office Add-ins*. This add-in technology is available in the desktop versions of Office only starting from Office 2013 (as well as on the mobile and browser-based Office versions). Earlier versions such as Office 2010 do *not* support this new technology.

Depending on your requirements you may choose one of the following options (which all are still fully supported in Office) to implement your Office solution:

- VSTO,
- COM add-ins,
- VBA templates
- Open XML

With the latter option you can even be completely independent from Office which makes it perfect for scenarios such as stand-alone document creation or (server-side) document manipulation.

Comment: Thank You Dirk.  I was coming to this conclusion, and I believe that VSTO is what I need for my environment of Visual Studio 2013 Professional and Office 2010, and my development requirements.  Do you know how to access the VSTO plug-ins when creating a project?  I get an Add-in for Word, but it doesn't appear to bring up a wizard or even have an entry like this in the project creation list, "Word VSTO Add-in."

Comment: Found IT!!!  Thanks to this post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f84e8fa-9ff4-406c-b4ff-68db5c7e917a/why-cant-i-debug-an-office-addin-using-office-2010-and-visual-studio-2013?forum=vsto

It was to do with the .NET Framework selection, and it works with .NET Framework 4 tro be able to select Word 2010 Document.  But on other machines, they have selections for Word 2010 Document using .NET Framework 4.5 and above, but I haven't had success using it, .. yet.